# Las Line's alignment is not proper

Tags: html, css

selected-works div's last lines's alignmet is not proper. It's text-align property has value of justify but there is a problem in last line. It is like left based not justify. Other lines have no any problem. How can I solve this problem?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: #000;
  text-align: center;
  color: rgb(231, 231, 231);
}

#wrapper {
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#hello {
  padding: 50px;
  border-bottom: 3px double rgb(185, 185, 185);
}

#avatar {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 130px;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#hello-header {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-size: 45px;
}

#header-p {
  font-size: 36px;
}

.link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(241, 225, 1);
}

.link:hover {
  color: gray;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

#selected-works {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 50px 0;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  text-align: justify;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

#sw-header {
  margin-bottom: 35px;
  text-align: center;
}

.work {
  width: 32%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}

.work img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.work img:hover {
  opacity: .5;
  transition: opacity .3s linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="hello">
    <img id="avatar" src="https://jonchretien.com/img/avatar.jpg">
    <h2 id="hello-header">Hello</h2>
    <p id="header-p">
      My name is Jon Chretien. I’m a <a class="link" href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_City">NYC</a> based front end engineer currently working on web apps for artists at <a class="link" href="https://www.spotify.com/">Spotify</a>. I previously
      built editorial & marketing projects at <a class="link" href="https://www.nytimes.com/">The New York Times</a>.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="selected-works">
    <h1 id="sw-header">Selected Works</h1>
    <div class="work">
      <a class="link" href="https://artists.spotify.com/blog/fan-insights-is-now-spotify-for-artists"><img src="https://jonchretien.com/img/work_s4a.jpg"></a>
      <h2><a class="link" href="https://artists.spotify.com/blog/fan-insights-is-now-spotify-for-artists">Spotify for Artists</a></h2>
      <p>Fan insights for artists & managers to discover more about their audience.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="work">
      <a class="link" href="https://artists.spotify.com/blog/fan-insights-is-now-spotify-for-artists"><img src="https://jonchretien.com/img/work_s4a.jpg"></a>
      <h2><a class="link" href="https://artists.spotify.com/blog/fan-insights-is-now-spotify-for-artists">Spotify for Artists</a></h2>
      <p>Fan insights for artists & managers to discover more about their audience.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="work">
      <a class="link" href="https://artists.spotify.com/blog/fan-insights-is-now-spotify-for-artists"><img src="https://jonchretien.com/img/work_s4a.jpg"></a>
      <h2><a class="link" href="https://artists.spotify.com/blog/fan-insights-is-now-spotify-for-artists">Spotify for Artists</a></h2>
      <p>Fan insights for artists & managers to discover more about their audience.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="work">
      <a class="link" href="https://artists.spotify.com/blog/fan-insights-is-now-spotify-for-artists"><img src="https://jonchretien.com/img/work_s4a.jpg"></a>
      <h2><a class="link" href="https://artists.spotify.com/blog/fan-insights-is-now-spotify-for-artists">Spotify for Artists</a></h2>
      <p>Fan insights for artists & managers to discover more about their audience.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="work">
      <a class="link" href="https://artists.spotify.com/blog/fan-insights-is-now-spotify-for-artists"><img src="https://jonchretien.com/img/work_s4a.jpg"></a>
      <h2><a class="link" href="https://artists.spotify.com/blog/fan-insights-is-now-spotify-for-artists">Spotify for Artists</a></h2>
      <p>Fan insights for artists & managers to discover more about their audience.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="work">
      <a class="link" href="https://artists.spotify.com/blog/fan-insights-is-now-spotify-for-artists"><img src="https://jonchretien.com/img/work_s4a.jpg"></a>
      <h2><a class="link" href="https://artists.spotify.com/blog/fan-insights-is-now-spotify-for-artists">Spotify for Artists</a></h2>
      <p>Fan insights for artists & managers to discover more about their audience.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="work">
      <a class="link" href="https://artists.spotify.com/blog/fan-insights-is-now-spotify-for-artists"><img src="https://jonchretien.com/img/work_s4a.jpg"></a>
      <h2><a class="link" href="https://artists.spotify.com/blog/fan-insights-is-now-spotify-for-artists">Spotify for Artists</a></h2>
      <p>Fan insights for artists & managers to discover more about their audience.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="work">
      <a class="link" href="https://artists.spotify.com/blog/fan-insights-is-now-spotify-for-artists"><img src="https://jonchretien.com/img/work_s4a.jpg"></a>
      <h2><a class="link" href="https://artists.spotify.com/blog/fan-insights-is-now-spotify-for-artists">Spotify for Artists</a></h2>
      <p>Fan insights for artists & managers to discover more about their audience.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="work">
      <a class="link" href="https://artists.spotify.com/blog/fan-insights-is-now-spotify-for-artists"><img src="https://jonchretien.com/img/work_s4a.jpg"></a>
      <h2><a class="link" href="https://artists.spotify.com/blog/fan-insights-is-now-spotify-for-artists">Spotify for Artists</a></h2>
      <p>Fan insights for artists & managers to discover more about their audience.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

selected-works div's last lines's alignmet is not proper. It's text-align property has value of justify but there is a problem in last line. It is like left based not justify. Other lines have no any problem. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default,

```
text-align: justify;
```

justifies all lines, except last one. If you also want the last line justified, you have to use [text-align-last](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-text-3/#text-align-last-property):

```
text-align-last: justify;
```

**Note:** This property is part of CSS text module 3 and current browser support sits at [77.98%](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-text-align-last).
To add support for it in legacy browsers, one would need to use a polyfill.

Comment: It worked but it also justify everything in selected-work div even other elements have different text-align properties.

Comment: Can you simplify your example and state in clear what is desired behavior? In current form, it's unclear what you want to justify and what you don't want to justify. It's probably a simple matter of setting correct selectors for you CSS. In the code you posted, you're not applying `text-align:justify` to anything. So please, state in clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: I want it to look like same with this site: https://jonchretien.com . But mine is look like this https://imgur.com/a/DJXvjLh . And you said that you are not applying text-align:justify to anything but i am applying for selected-works div.

Comment: The example site doesn't use `text-align:justify`. It uses `text-align:left`. And the texts below the images **are not justified**!

Comment: Yes, but it uses grid. Is it possible to have same effect without using grid? If i change text-align: justify with left it wouldn't be same. And why  the texts below the images are not justified despite i use different text-align properties for them.

Comment: What *"same effect"* are you talking about? In your example, `.work { text-align: left;}` makes it left justified. If you change it, it will change the text alignment. Note `text-align` set on parent does not work on children if the children have a set `text-align`. So you'd need `#selected-works > div {text-align: justify;}` to work (they two selectors need to target the same element: the child).

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. I solved it by applying text-align-last property for children of selected work div. If they have only text-align property I guess parent div's text-align-last property has priority.